# How to require an object based on the value of an array using Joi validation

Tags: node.js, joi

I am setting up validation for my api and need to require a phone number to be present if the notification the client would like to get is set to sms. The notification is set in the validation schema. I have the following code here that will illustrate this better, please note the `.required().when()` section. This makes the phone number field required every time, no matter what the `notification_type` array contains.

```
{
    body: {
        notification_type: Joi.array().unique().items(Joi.string().lowercase().valid(['sms', 'email')).min(1).max(3).optional(),
        customer: Joi.object().keys({
            first_name: Joi.string().required(),
            last_name: Joi.string().required(),
            email_address: Joi.string().email().required(),
            phone_number: Joi.string(), // make this required if notification_type contains 'sms'
            meta_data: Joi.object().optional()
        }).required().when('notification_type', {
            is: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid('sms')),
            then: Joi.object({ phone_number: Joi.required() })
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the phone number to be **optional** if the notification type array doesn't include **sms** and **required** if it does, you can define something like this:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    notification_type: Joi.array().items(
        Joi.string().valid('email', 'sms')
    ),
    customer: Joi.object({
        phone_number: Joi.string(),
    })
}).when(Joi.object({
    notification_type: Joi.array().items(
        Joi.string().valid('sms').required(),
        Joi.string().valid('email').optional()
    )
}).unknown(), {
    then: Joi.object({
        customer: Joi.object({
            phone_number: Joi.string().required()
        }).required()
    }),
    otherwise: Joi.object({
        customer: Joi.object({
            phone_number: Joi.optional()
        })
    })
});
```

So, the following object will be accepted:

```
{
   notification_type:[
      'sms',
      'email'
   ],
   customer:{
      phone_number:'111-222-333'
   }
}
```

and this won't:

```
{
   notification_type:[
      'sms'
   ],
   customer:{

   }
}
```

Comment: Actually the other way around. If sms is in the array, phone is required, otherwise phone is optional.Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
phone_number: body.notification_type === 'sms' ? Joi.string().required() : Joi.string()
```

?

Comment: Thanks but this seems very hacky-I don't see the point of using Joi if this were to be used. There would also be an error as notification_type is an array not a string. We'd have to use some sort of contains to make it work like this.